# Broadcast gives multiple fires on using PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION - SOLUTION

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-gps

Hello guys I am using Broadcast Receiver in my project that gives me multiple outputs at one time while enabling and disabling GPS. How to solve that??

Here is a log that will give multiple outputs like this

```
MyBroadcastReceivers﹕ IsGPS = true
MyBroadcastReceivers﹕ IsGPS = true
MyBroadcastReceivers﹕ IsGPS = true
MyBroadcastReceivers﹕ IsGPS = true
```

Here is my Solution code

```
public class MyBroadcastReceivers extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static boolean isGpsEnabled,isPermissionAskedOnce=true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGpsEnabled = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            

            if(isGpsEnabled){
                   //do you stuff
                    isPermissionAskedOnce=true;
            }else{
                 
                if(isPermissionAskedOnce){
                  //do your stuff 
                    isPermissionAskedOnce=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```